# Arrays pointers on 32bit and 64bit systems

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

The following code prints different results on 32bit and 64bit systems:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void swapArray(int **a, int **b) 
{ 
    int *temp = *a; 
    *a = *b; 
    *b = temp; 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    int a[2] = {1, 3}; 
    int b[2] = {2, 4}; 
    swapArray(&a, &b); 
    printf("%d\n", a[0]); 
    printf("%d\n", a[1]); 
    return 0; 
}
```

After compiling it in 32bit system, the output is:

```
2
3
```

On 64bit the output is:

```
2
4
```

As I understand, the function `swapArray` just swaps the pointers to the first elements in `a` and `b`. So after calling `swapArray`, `a` should point to `2` and `b` should point to `1`.
For this reason `a[0]` should yield `2`, and `a[1]` should reference the next byte in memory after the location of `2`, which contains `4`.

Can anyone please explain?

**Edit:**
Thanks to the comments and answers, I now notice that `&a` and `&b` are of type `int (*)[]` and not `int **`. This obviously makes the code incorrect (and indeed I get a compiler warning). It is intriguing, though, why the compiler (gcc) just gives a warning and not an error.
I am still left with the question what causes different results on different systems, but since the code is incorrect, it is less relevant.

**Edit 2:**
As for the different results on different systems, I suggest reading [AndreyT's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703960/arrays-pointers-on-32bit-and-64bit-systems#comment15523522_11704003).

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. Arrays are arrays. Pointers are pointers. Arrays can decay to pointers, but they are not pointers.

Comment: Note that `&a` is of the type `pointer to array of int[2]`, not `pointer to pointer to int`.

Comment: What are you expecting this line to do: `*a = *b;`?

Comment: The C standard doesn't distinguish between warnings and error messages; it just requires diagnostics for certain kinds of errors (violations of syntax rules and constraints). gcc often issues warnings for invalid things that the authors think you might want to do anyway.

Comment: -1 for not including the (very significant) compiler warning message in your initial post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
swapArray(&a, &b);
```

`&a` and `&b` are not of type `int **` but of type `int (*)[2]`. BTW your compiler is kind enough to accept your program but a compiler has the right to refuse to translate it.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice it. But in that case, how you might explain the difference between 32 and 64 bit? And also, how is it that the compiler does accept it and doesn't mark an error?

Comment: @EyalAr: The compiler didn't report an error because your compiler's settings are set for "loose" error checking. Use more pedantic settings and the error will be reported. In any case, the compiler probably issued a warning. Formally, this is already good enough.

Comment: @EyalAr: As for the difference... When you forcefully interpreted your arrays as "pointers", you actually reinterpreted (and swapped) your array elements. Type `int` has 4-byte size on both of your platforms, while pointers change from 4 bytes (32 bit) to 8 bytes (64 bit). On 64-bit platform pointer reinterpretation covered two `int` elements of the array, so two elements of each array got swapped. On 32-bit platform only one element of each array got swapped.

Comment: @AndreyT, It's now clear. +1 for the good explanation. Thank you.

Comment: @KeithThompson I agree, *kind* is maybe not the most appropriate word here ;)

Answer (score 5):

Before answering your question lets see what happens under the hood during a pointer operation. I'm using a very simple code to demonstrate this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        int *p;
        int **p2;
        int x = 3;
        p = &x;
        p2 = &p;
        return 0;
}
```

Now look at the disassembly :

```
(gdb) disassemble 
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000400474 <+0>: push   rbp
   0x0000000000400475 <+1>: mov    rbp,rsp
   0x0000000000400478 <+4>: mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x14],0x3
   0x000000000040047f <+11>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x14]
   0x0000000000400483 <+15>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],rax
   0x0000000000400487 <+19>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x10]
   0x000000000040048b <+23>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
=> 0x000000000040048f <+27>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x0000000000400494 <+32>:    leave  
   0x0000000000400495 <+33>:    ret
```

The disassembly is pretty self evident. But a few note need to be added here,

My function's stack frame starts from here:

```
   0x0000000000400474 <+0>: push   rbp
   0x0000000000400475 <+1>: mov    rbp,rsp
```

So lets what they have for now

```
(gdb) info registers $rbp
rbp            0x7fffffffe110   0x7fffffffe110
```

here we are putting value `3` in `[rbp - 0x14]`'s address. lets see the memory map

```
(gdb) x/1xw $rbp - 0x14
0x7fffffffe0fc: 0x00000003
```

Its important to notice the `DWORD` datatype is used, which is a 32 bits wide. So on the side note, integer literals like `3` is treated treated as 4 bytes unit.

Next instruction uses `lea` to load the effective address of the value just saved in earlier instruction.

```
0x000000000040047f <+11>:   lea    rax,[rbp-0x14]
```

It means that now `$rax` will have the value `0x7fffffffe0fc`.

```
(gdb) p/x $rax
$4 = 0x7fffffffe0fc
```

Next we will save this address into memory using

```
0x0000000000400483 <+15>:   mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],rax
```

Important thing to note that a `QWORD` which is used here. Because 64bit systems have 8 byte native pointer size. `0x14 - 0x10 = 4` bytes were used in earlier `mov` instruction.

Next we have :

```
   0x0000000000400487 <+19>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x10]
   0x000000000040048b <+23>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
```

This is again for the second indirection. always all the value related to addresses are `QWORD`. This is important thing  to take a  note of this.

Now lets come to your code.

Before calling to swaparray you have :

```
=> 0x00000000004004fe <+8>: mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],0x1
   0x0000000000400505 <+15>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc],0x3
   0x000000000040050c <+22>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x20],0x2
   0x0000000000400513 <+29>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x1c],0x4
   0x000000000040051a <+36>:    lea    rdx,[rbp-0x20]
   0x000000000040051e <+40>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x10]
   0x0000000000400522 <+44>:    mov    rsi,rdx
   0x0000000000400525 <+47>:    mov    rdi,rax
```

This is very trivial. Your array is initialized and the effect of `&` operator is visible when the effective address of the start of array is loaded into `$rdi` and `$rsi`.

Now lets see what its doing inside `swaparray()`.

The start of your array is saved into `$rdi` and `$rsi`. So lets see their contents

```
(gdb) p/x  $rdi
$2 = 0x7fffffffe100
(gdb) p/x  $rsi
$3 = 0x7fffffffe0f0



   0x00000000004004c8 <+4>: mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18],rdi
   0x00000000004004cc <+8>: mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20],rsi
```

Now the first statement `int *temp = *a` is performed by following instructions.

```
   0x00000000004004d0 <+12>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18]
   0x00000000004004d4 <+16>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rax]
   0x00000000004004d7 <+19>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
```

Now comes the defining moment, what's happening with your `*a`?

1. It loads into `$rax` the value stored in `[rbp - 0x18]`. where the value `$rdi` was saved. which in turn holds the address of the first element of the first array.
2. performs another indirection by using the address stored into `$rax` to fetch a `QWARD` and loads it into `$rax`. So what it will return? it will return a `QWARD` from `0x7fffffffe100`. Which will in effect form a 8 byte quantity from two four byte quantity saved there. To elaborate,

The memory there is like below.

```
(gdb) x/2xw $rdi
0x7fffffffe100: 0x00000001  0x00000003
```

Now if you fetch a `QWORD`

```
(gdb) x/1xg $rdi
0x7fffffffe100: 0x0000000300000001
```

So already you are actually screwed. Because you are fetching with incorrect boundary.

The rest of the codes can be explained in similar manner.

Now why its different in 32 bit platform? because in 32 bit platform the native pointer width is 4 bytes. So the thing here will be different there. The main problem with your semantically incorrect code originates from the difference in integer type width and native pointer types. If you have both the same, you may still work around your code.

But you should never write code which assumes the size of native types. That's why standards are for. that's why your compiler is giving you warning.

From language point of view its a type mismatch which is already pointed out in the earlier answers so i'm not going into that.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough and extensive answer!

Answer (score 3):

You can't swap arrays using the pointer trick (they are not pointers!).  You would either have to create pointers to those arrays and use the pointers or dynamically allocate the arrays using malloc etc.

The results I get on a 64-bit system are different than yours for example, I get:

```
2
3

test: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, not stripped
```

And with clang on my mac I get an error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:13: error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[2]’ to ‘int**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void swapArray(int**, int**)’
```

I assume that this is undefined behavior and you are trying to interpret what is probably junk output.

Comment: Thank you @gww, I am aware of it, but since this is a homework question, I was intrigued by the results of the given code. I'm not looking to correct it, but rather to understand the problem.

Comment: @EyalAr: I believe what you are doing is undefined behavior but I may be incorrect.  The results are are getting is _probably_ random junk.